# Places API returns REQUEST_DENIED for some special characters

Tags: api, hash, character

We are using the Google places API in our application... it searches
for the address correctly.

But when the address contains some special characters, e.g. "#101"
etc, it fails with a **REQUEST_DENIED error**. Whereas the same address
works fine on the Google maps website.

I have verified that my **API key**, **URL**, **Address**, **Sensor parameter** etc.
all are correct. The same query starts to fail when we add special
character # in the query.

I have also tried the javascript's encodeURL function but had no
benefit. I have also tried replacing # sign with # but had the
same result.

[Example URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=pizza%20highway%20#101&sensor=false&key=My_Key)

Please help.